# C# - How to activate a textbox in a Windows Form based on a specific value from another textbox

Tags: c#

I'm kinda new in Visual Studio, C# programming,I am trying to make an input application and some help will be much apprecieted :).
At one point,i want to "activate" some textboxes based on a value from another one.
For instance, let's say that i have in total 5 textboxes. One of them is a combobox with 2 values (A and B).
While this combobox is empty or user select A, the other 4 texboxes i want to be in readonly state and when B value is selected , i need them to activate.
Simple as that but i don't realy know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean: activate? You mean get focus on it? Active to type on?

Comment: WinForms?  Select the ComboBox.  In the Properties Pane, click on the Lightning Bolt to show the Events.  Scroll down and find the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netcore-3.1) entry and double click it.  In that event stub, you can place code to change the state of the other controls based on the current selection.

Comment: @PeymanMajidi...activate...i mean to be able to type into it. Initial state ,when the app is launched, is readonly and i want to stay like this until B value is selected. When user will select B, i want that those fields to be editable.

Comment: @Idle_Mind..your solution sounds well. Thanks. I will give it a try and i will let you know if it works.